# How to use rollup with Leaflet 1.1.0 to create a single bundle?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, leaflet, rollupjs

I noticed that Leaflet has moved to using ES6 modules and rollup.

http://leafletjs.com/2017/06/27/leaflet-1.1.0.html

Given this, I would to try to bundle LeafLet, and various plugins, along with my app into a single file.

I am using the simplest tutorial from the leaflet site as a test case.

I am running into a problem that when I create the bundle the following error is generated:

```
⚠️   The 'this' keyword is equivalent to 'undefined' at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten
https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#this-is-undefined
node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js (9:2)
 7:   typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
 8:   (factory((global.L = global.L || {})));
 9: }(this, (function (exports) { 'use strict';
```

For my test the index.js file is:

```
import 'leaflet';

function leafletTest() {

        var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                        '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                        'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
                id: 'mapbox.streets'
        }).addTo(mymap);

}

export default leafletTest;
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "leaflet-rollup-test",
  "description": "A test to see how to use leaflet with rollup",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "dist/leaflet-test.js",
  "style": "dist/leaflet-test.css",
  "license": "Mit",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "leaflet": "^1.1.0",
    "rollup": "^0.45.2",
    "rollup-plugin-json": "^2.3.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c ./rollup.config.js"
  }
}
```

My rollup.config.js file:

```
// rollup.config.js

import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import json from 'rollup-plugin-json';

export default {
  entry: 'index.js',
  format: 'umd',
  moduleName: 'leafletTest',
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      // pass custom options to the resolve plugin
      customResolveOptions: {
        moduleDirectory: 'node_modules'
      }
    }),
    json()
  ],
  dest: 'dist/leafletTest.js'
};
```

The bundle is generated in dist/leafletTest.js

My index.html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

        <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/leafletTest.css" />
        <script src="dist/leafletTest.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>    
        leafletTest();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get an error in the console:

```
leafletTest.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'L' of undefined
    at version (leafletTest.js:14)
    at leafletTest.js:15
    at leafletTest.js:4
    at leafletTest.js:5
```

How do I import leaflet so that it gets usably bundled?

I suspect that I am missing something very basic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leaflet does not specify yet an ES module entry for module loaders consumption (no `"module"` or `"jsnext:main"` in its `package.json` file).

Therefore Rollup will use the standard `"main"` file, i.e. the UMD-wrapped `dist/leaflet-src.js` file, which triggers the error you report.

You can very easily have Rollup correctly manage UMD dependencies by using the [`rollup-plugin-commonjs`](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs) after your resolver:

```js
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    commonjs()
  ],
  // other options…
};
```

That being said, since you use Rollup and `rollup-plugin-json`, you could directly use the Leaflet entry file instead of its built UMD version:

```js
import 'leaflet/src/Leaflet';
```

or

```
import * as L from 'leaflet/src/Leaflet';
```

With this Rollup will be able to Tree Shake Leaflet as well, even though it is not very optimized now for that purpose.

For reference, this feature is currently being discussed (see [Leaflet #5620](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/5620))

Note: due to the "hack" in current Leaflet entry file to set the global `window.L`, you have to export something (can be anything, like `export var dummy = true`) from your own entry file (and therefore specify a `moduleName` config / `--name` CLI option) so that `exports` is defined.

Comment: This is excellent and exactly what I was missing. I now have a much better understanding how these pieces fit together.

Comment: It looks like I have it working now with one exception. After running it through rollup I'm getting a parse error on a line which I've traced to leaflet/src/Leaflet.js at line 35:

window.L = exports;

exports does not seem to be defined. Setting it to an empty variable causes it to load. Bug?

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to mention this particularity. See the note in the above edited answer.

Comment: How can I solve this issue when using rollup with react-leaflet?

Comment: @ZaidRehman please feel free to open a new question with specific details of your issue.

Comment: The issue is pretty same so I think it will be marked duplicate.
I am having the same error but my code is not importing leaflet, its react-leaflet which is importing it. So I can't import leaflet from src instead of dist